# Как исправить ошибку SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain при cURL запросе?

Tags: парсер, curl, proxy, прокси, php-curl

Пытаюсь парсить с помощью cURL через прокси, но возвращается ошибка: Ошибка curl: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain. Запрос такой отправляю:

```
public function sendRequest() {
        
        $proxy_ip = '174.77.111.196:4145';

       $url = 'https://bycicles.ru/types/?mode=search&request=' . urlencode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$headers = [
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0'
    ]; // создаем заголовки

$curl = curl_init(); // создаем экземпляр curl

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false); // 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
    echo 'Операция завершена без каких-либо ошибок';
}

return $result;
        
    }
```

Использовал бесплатные прокси отсюда: https://hidemy.io/ru/proxy-list/?start=12288#list

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил и через 5 минут правильный ответ попался, нужно всего лишь отключить проверку SSL

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);